# How can I format a partition into a filesystem quickly?

Tags: filesystems, mkfs

In gparted, repartitioning a disk into one single partition and formatting the partition to a filesystem is very fast. It seems not write zeros to the partition.

How can I achieve the same when using commands? Here is what I got:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ntfs /dev/sdb1
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Initializing device with zeroes:  14% 16%
```

Answer (score 45):

If you would like to format a partition as NTFS, please use `mkfs.ntfs` or `mkntfs`. From `man mkfs`:

```
This  mkfs  frontend  is  deprecated  in  favour of filesystem specific
mkfs.<type> utils.
```

For NTFS, you can add the `-f` or `-Q` flag to perform a quick format. From `man mkntfs`:

```
-f, --fast, -Q, --quick
       Perform  quick  (fast) format. This will skip both zeroing of the volume and bad sector checking.
```

Therefore, your command should be:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Thanks. Why "This  mkfs  frontend  is  deprecated  in  favour of filesystem specific
mkfs.<type> utils."?

Comment: @Tim why do you keep asking why things are deprecated? If the documentation tells you so, isn’t that good enough for you?

Comment: @Tim glad it worked. Would you please mark my answer as accepted if it lead you to a solution? I can only speculate why it has been deprecated. Probably because it's a good approach to have specialised tools for such complicated operations.

Comment: ... And as of 2022-08-07 Tim has not yet awarded any points.  Tsk, tsk..